# Return Missing Rows from Python SQL Query

Tags: python, sql-server, postgresql

Is there anyway i can compare two different databases (postgresl, sql server) and return the missing rows? I am missing one row in the postgresql table that is not in the sql server one and have no clue how to return that answer to me.

I have two connections opened for postgresql (bpo_table_results) and for sql server(rps_table_results)

postgresql table:

```
date     count   amount
1/1/21    500    1,234,654.12
```

sql server table:

```
date      count   amount
1/1/21    500    1,234,654.12
1/2/21    4541   3,457,787.24
```

expected results:

```
The row in the amount of 3,457,787.24 is missing from your posgresql table.
```

code:

```
def queryRPS(sql_server_conn, sql_server_cursor):
    rps_item_count_l = []
    rps_icl_amt_l = []

    rps_table_q_2 = f"""select * from rps..sendfile where processingdate = '{cd}' and datasetname like '%ICL%' """
    rps_table_results = sql_server_cursor.execute(rps_table_q_2).fetchall()

    for row in rps_table_results:
        rps_item_count = row[16]
        rps_item_count_l.append(rps_item_count)
        rps_icl_amt = row[18]
        rps_icl_amt_l.append(rps_icl_amt)

def queryBPO(postgres_conn, postgres_cursor,rps_item_count_l, rps_icl_amt_l):

    bpo_results_l = []
    rps_results_l = []

    for rps_count, rps_amount in zip(rps_item_count_l, rps_icl_amt_l):
        rps_amount_f = str(rps_amount).rstrip('0')
        rps_amount_f = ("{:,}".format(float(rps_amount_f)))
        bpo_icl_awk_q_2 = """select * from ppc_data.icl_awk where num_items = '%s' and
                            file_total = '%s' """ % (str(rps_count), str(rps_amount_f))

        postgres_cursor.execute(bpo_icl_awk_q_2)
        bpo_table_results = postgres_cursor.fetchall()

        rps_table_q_2 = f"""select * from rps..sendfile where processingdate = '{cd}' and datasetname like '%ICL%' """
        rps_table_results = sql_server_cursor.execute(rps_table_q_2).fetchall()

rps_item_count_l, rps_icl_amt_l = queryRPS(sql_server_conn, sql_server_cursor)
queryBPO(postgres_conn, postgres_cursor, rps_item_count_l, rps_icl_amt_l)
```

Comment: "set" and "Counter" objects provide set-operations which can be helpful here. You just have to ensure that equal rows also produce equal tuples (column order, float precision,...).

Comment: Have you tried creating a linked server connection from SQL to Postgres and then executing `select * from postgres.database.schema.table where... except select * from sqlServer.database.schema.table where...` to see if it's really missing?